# Re-write segment of a compiled C program

Tags: c, visual-studio, encryption, memory-management, segment

I've a C program structured in this way:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma section(".code",execute, read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")
#pragma code_seg(".code")

//Code to decrypt

#pragma section(".stub", execute, read, write)
#pragma code_seg(".stub")

void decryptor(){
    //Retrieve virtual address of the pointer to the .code section
    //Retrieve the virtual size of the pointer to the .code section
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
         //HERE THE PROGRAM STOPS
         ptrCode[0] = //Reverse function of the encryptor
    }
}

int main(){
    decryptor();
    mainFunctionDecrypted();
    return 0;
}
```

Basically i've an encryptor which first encrypt the .code segment in the exe of this program after compilation.
Then when i execute the modified exe i want to be able to first decrypt it and then execute the decrypted part. However it seems like i cannot write to the .code segment loaded in memory (I think because it's a part memory dedicated to code to be executed).

Is there any way to write to executable memory?

Is there any workaroud you would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to modify the code in the following way. Moreover there are important compiler option to set in visual studio, for example to disable the Data Execution Prevention.

**Compiler option used:** 
/permissive- /GS /TC /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Zc:inline /fp:precise /Zp1 /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR- /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /nologo /diagnostics:classic

**Linker option used:** 
/MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT:NO /DYNAMICBASE:NO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /FIXED /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /MAP /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

```
#pragma section(".code", execute, read)
#pragma section(".codedata", read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.codedata,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/MERGE:.codedata=.code")

//All the following will go in code
#pragma code_seg(".code")
#pragma data_seg(".codedata")
#pragma const_seg(".codedata")

//CODE TO DECRYPT

// .stub SECTION
#pragma section(".stub", execute, read)
#pragma section(".stubdata", read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.stub,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.stubdata,ERW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/MERGE:.stubdata=.stub")

//All the following will go in .stub segment
#pragma code_seg(".stub")
#pragma data_seg(".stubdata")
#pragma const_seg(".stubdata")

/*This function needs to be changed to whatever correspond to the decryption function of the encryotion function used by the encryptor*/
void decryptCodeSection(){

     //Retrieve virtual address of the pointer to the .code section
     //Retrieve the virtual size of the pointer to the .code section
     for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
          //HERE THE PROGRAM STOPS
          ptrCode[0] = //Reverse function of the encryptor
      }

void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    decryptor();
    mainFunctionDecrypted();
}
```

Doing this way i was able to first decrypt the segment and then execute the function.

Answer (score 3):

Windows and other operating systems go out of their way to prevent you from doing this (modifying the code sections of a running application).

Your immediate options, then, are

1) decrypt the code to some other memory area allocated dynamically for that purpose (code must then either use only position-independent instructions, or contain custom fixups for the instructions that have position-specific data).

2) use a separate program that decrypts the program on disk before it is executed.

Comment: Assuming that i use position independent instruction (for semplicity sake), once i've dinamically allocated the required memory and decrypted the segment there what should i do to be able to call `mainFunctionDecrypted()` ? To be more clear, what do i've to do to access to thos function? Anyway thanks for your fast reply

Comment: To call the code, use a function pointer. The exact syntax for this varies depending on the programming language, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscating a program in this way is inherently futile.  Whatever your "decryptor" does, a human who is determined to reverse engineer your program can also do.  Spend your effort instead on making your program desirable enough that people *want* to pay you for it, and benevolent enough that you don't have to hide what it's doing.